# Is there a good known algorithm for generating sets of monomials?  (Alternatively, what is the fastest known algorithm for generating integer partitions?)

Tags: nt.number-theory

I'm interested in efficiently generating (or iterating over) sets of all monomials of a degree $n$ over $r$ variables,, up to relabeling variables; this can be identified with the set of partitions of $n$ into at most $r$ parts.

More generally, I need to efficiently generate (or iterate over) the set of all sets of $k$ distinct monomials of degree $n$ over $r$ variables, up to relabeling variables.  I can think of a few ways to solve both problems, but nothing that isn't extremely computationally intensive.  Are there good known algorithms for these computations?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can try looking at the bottom of this page
http://www.math.ias.edu/~bober/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See Chapter 7.2.1.4 of Knuth "The Art of Computer Programming" Vol. 4 Fascicle 3.  On page 38 he gives algorithms to efficiently enumerate all partitions of an integer $n$ (see Algorithm P), or to enumerate all partitions of $n$ into exactly $m$ parts (see Algorithm H).  Running Algorithm H repeatedly with $m$ varying from 1 to $r$ should solve your problem in essentially optimal time (i.e. within a constant factor of the size of the output).

Answer (score 0):

See Fast Algorithm for Generating Ascending Compositions in Journal of Mathematical Modelling and Algorithms,  11(1), 89-104 (2012) DOI: 10.1007/s10852-011-9168-y.